# How to send file to riemann server?

Tags: clojure, riemann

I have setup riemann server, now I want to send log file to riemann server. How can i do that? I did not find any helpful material from internet.

Answer (score 2):

You don't send files to riemann servers, you send events. You might want to look at some of the documentation around the [riemann client libraries](https://github.com/aphyr/riemann-clojure-client) for details of how to send events.

```
(use 'riemann.client)
(def c (tcp-client {:host "1.2.3.4"}))
(send-event c {:service "foo" :state "ok"})
```

It may also be worth checking out the [basic concepts page](http://riemann.io/concepts.html) This explains what riemann is in more detail.